# Offline App using Open Street Map and HTML5

Tags: html, openstreetmap

We want to create an offline map application and here's my thoughts on how I will implement it:

- Download map data from OSM (XML)
- Store OSM map data on the client browser
- Render map using an API

My problems:

- Downloading data from OSM, they only allow a small portion of the map to be exported, and I don't want to download 30GB database. Is there an application that can download map data of a whole country for me?
- Rendering the map, what is the best JavaScript API for OSM? It should allow working offline and preferably, those with capability of rendering routes.

Comment: For the first question: http://download.geofabrik.de/ has a number of osm extracts per country or state.

Comment: @SlavenRezic Did that! :D Unfortunately when extracted, the file size became 900mb! I can't load that to browser.

Comment: @dpp Of course not, live-rendering a whole country requires a lot of resources. You need to feed a smaller amount to the browser containing only the visible area, only features you want to render and only features visible for the current zoom level. The extract contains way more information than you will need.

Answer (score 1):

As already mentioned by SlavenRezic there are [country and area extracts](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Planet.osm#Country_and_area_extracts) available. The only reason why exporting large areas via the main API isn't allowed are performance reasons because that would involve running a rather heavy query on the main database. Alternatively you could download the whole [planet](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Planet.osm) and [split](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/OSM_file_formats#Splitting_one_big_file_into_different_geographical_regions) it into geographical regions yourself or try using the [Overpass API](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Overpass_API) which is significantly faster than the main API.

For [rendering](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Rendering) a map there are various [libraries](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Renderers#Libraries) available. Choose the one that fits your needs. I'm not sure if anyone is able to display a route because their main purpose is rendering. But maybe you can use [LeafLet](http://switch2osm.org/using-tiles/getting-started-with-leaflet/) or [OpenLayers](http://switch2osm.org/using-tiles/getting-started-with-openlayers/) to create an overlay on top of your rendered map.